# How to keep track of how many read/write operations are performed...?

Tags: c, file-io, buffer, read-write

For class I was given this, "Develop a C program that copies an input file to an output file and counts the number of read/write operations." I know how to do the action copying the input file to the output file, but I am not entirely sure how to keep track of how many read/write operation were performed. This program is supposed to repeat the copying using different buffer sizes and output a listing of the number of read/write operations performed with each buffer size. I am just not sure how to do the part of counting the r/w operations. How could one go about doing this? Thank you in advance.

Here is my current code (updated):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "apue.h"
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 1

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    int input_file;
    int output_file;
    int readCount = 0;
    int writeCount = 0;

    input_file = open("test.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if(input_file < 0)
    {
        printf("could not open file.\n");
    }

    output_file = creat("output.txt", FILE_MODE);

    if(output_file < 0)
    {
        printf("error with output file.\n");
    }


    while((n = read(input_file, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0)
    {
        readCount++;
        if(write(output_file, buf, n) == n){
            writeCount++;
        }else{
            printf("Error writing");
        }
    }

    if(n < 0)
    {
        printf("reading error");
    }

    printf("read/write count: %d\n", writeCount + readCount);
    printf("read = %d\n", readCount);
    printf("write = %d\n", writeCount);

}
```

And for the text file: test one two

The result is:

```
read/write count: 26
read = 13
write = 13

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.003 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

I was thinking that the write would be 12...but I am not sure...

Comment: the code is missing #include <stdio.h>

Comment: the posted code fails to close the files after all the read/write operations are completed.

Comment: the main() function states that is returns an int, however, the code is missing the 'return value;' statement

Comment: 'FILE_MODE' is being used, but never defined

Comment: when compiling, always enable all warnings, then fix the warnings.  Warnings a indications from the compiler that the compiler thinks some code is probably wrong

Answer (score 0):

You will need to increment a variable every time you call a function that does reading or writing. You may do that by making a function that wraps the standard i/o function.

For example, replace fread with something like this:

```
size_t fread_count(void *p, size_t size, size_t num, FILE *f){
    iocount++;
    return fread(p, size, num, f);
}
```

iocount would have to be in scope (e.g. global)

If you need to count reads and writes separately, use separate variables.
One that you increment for reads and one that you increment for writes.
-edit-
since you are using write() and read(), you could easily make an equivalent
function like above but using write and read instead of fwrite and fread

Comment: so if my test file contained this: "test one two"

what should be returned if I use one variable, and my buffer size is 1? @smeezekitty

Comment: these proposed functions could/should have another parameter that is the address of the counter, then the counter would not need to be 'global' (actually file global by using the 'static' modifier)

Comment: @PhilectorIV I think that it would be 25. One for each byte read and one for each byte written. And one extra for the attempted read at the end of file

Comment: @user3629249 You are right. That would be a better way to do it in the long run to avoid the code getting cluttered with global variables. I used the global variable example for simplicity. But using a pointer would be better general coding practice.

Answer (score 0):

to help with trying different buffer sizes:

1) put the open/read/write/close and char buffer[], read/write counters, final printf statement for counters, etc into a separate function

2) in main(), add a table that contains the buffer sizes to be tried.

3) call the new function from main(), 
   including a parameter that indicates the buffer size to use